# How to define $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not exactly understand what this question is asking.

So, it is given to let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Then, I must "define that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix.

I currently understand that in order to solve for a matrix's eigenvalues (at least how my professor describes it), one must use the following equation:
$$ 0 = \det(A- \lambda I) $$
How does one go about proving this? I do not understand how i can take the determinant this matrix, let alone solve the equation above.

Comment: Also, I very much apologize for all the mistakes in the post. First time posting here and I ruined the formatting.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ **iff** there is some $v \neq 0$ such that $A v = \lambda v$ **iff** $(A-\lambda I) v  =0$ **iff** $\ker (A-\lambda I)$ is non trivial **iff** $\det (A -\lambda I)$  is zero.

Comment: I don't know why you write that you cannot take the $\det$ of the matrix.

Comment: That is what was confusing me the most. The fact that you cant take a determinant of a matrix with no numbers. We have not been introduced to kernels yet, so I do not think i could use the technique you posted. This professor will most definitely take off points for notusing "his" method.  Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: I'm nit sure what you mean. For any given $A$ and $\lambda$ the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is just a matrix of numbers, and you can take the determinant of that. Just like the formula $x^2$ represents a number, but is only a number when you give a specific value for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Given a square matrix $A$ we say $\lambda$ an eigen value for $A$ if associated with $\lambda$ atleast one vector $v \neq 0$ such that

$$Av = \lambda v$$.

Suppose that the eigen value $\lambda$ is known then we have a nonzero $v$ such that

$$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$.

Since we assumed $v$ is non zero the new matrix $A_{\lambda}:= A-\lambda I$ is not invertible. Thus we must have

$$\det A_\lambda=\det (A-\lambda I)=0$$.

Comment: Thanks! Seeing this written out neatly makes it a lot less complicated for my linear-algebra-lacking mind. Really appreciate it.